# find div position which contains both align center and class myClass using Regex php

Tags: php, html, regex

I have to find the position of div which contains align="center" and class="myClass" both (irrespective of the order) in a HTML Block

Please help me with regex pattern

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Don't go for regex instead of that go for DOM object traversal method. Read here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Comment: Yes. I'm working on that now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would it be possible to use XPath instead like with dom xpath? then you could use `//div[contains(@align, 'center') and contains(@class, 'myClass')]` instead

Comment: Yes. I used it that way and I'm able to fetch it. But My actual requirement is I need to find the position of above div in the given string.

Comment: In the above query how can I include parent node too?

Comment: @Phpian `//div[contains(@align, 'center') and contains(@class, 'myClass')]/..`

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Let me try that.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make much sense to search in PHP which runs on the server, you should use Javascript/JQuery for that. In JQuery you can use selectors that are very simple to use, for your use it would be `$('div .myClass [align="center"]')` and then use a method that returns the position.
Here's the doc for JQuery https://api.jquery.com/

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I really need it at the backend processing, so I'm using php. Im trying to do this with dom object now.